# Delete top and bottom entire rows if value is lower than -50

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I have the below data set:

| Profit | MRO 15x5 | D30 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $150.00 | -9.189 | -0.24 |
| $12.50 | -6.076 | -0.248 |
| -$125.00 | -7.699 | -0.282 |
| -$162.50 | -8.008 | -0.281 |
| -$175.00 | -0.183 | -0.056 |
| -$175.00 | -0.235 | -0.061 |
| $275.00 | 0.141 | -0.027 |
| -$175.00 | -4.062 | -0.103 |
| -$162.50 | -5.654 | -0.258 |
| -$162.50 | -1.578 | -0.051 |
| -$175.00 | -3.336 | -0.205 |
| -$162.50 | -1.523 | -0.022 |
| $412.50 | -1.524 | -0.194 |
| $337.50 | -1.049 | -0.055 |
| $100.00 | -1.043 | -0.059 |

I want to first arrange column D30 in ascending order and then look into the Profit column. If the top n row and bottom n row values (a range of cells) are less than -50 in the Profit column then delete the entire row in the data set.

The result would be like this:

| Profit | MRO 15x5 | D30 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $275.00 | 0.141 | -0.027 |
| -$162.50 | -1.578 | -0.051 |
| $337.50 | -1.049 | -0.055 |
| -$175.00 | -0.183 | -0.056 |
| $100.00 | -1.043 | -0.059 |
| -$175.00 | -0.235 | -0.061 |
| -$175.00 | -4.062 | -0.103 |
| $412.50 | -1.524 | -0.194 |
| -$175.00 | -3.336 | -0.205 |
| $150.00 | -9.189 | -0.24 |
| $12.50 | -6.076 | -0.248 |

This output is the result of the deletion of the top 1st row and bottom 3 rows from the entire data set as these rows (range of values) were having Profit values less than -50.

Can anyone please help me to do this in the R program using dplyr or by using some other filtering packages?

I would be thankful for your kind support.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: To clarify, by "ascending" it sounds like you mean "getting more negative"? And you want to remove all the contiguous first and last rows with profit < -50?

Comment: Dear Jon, thanks for your quick response. Yes it may result in more negative values in Profit column. And then top and bottom all negative contiguous values in Profit which are less than -50 should be removed and this deletion should be of entire rows. If the top or bottom first value is positive then the range of cells from top or bottom whose sum is less than -50, then entire subset should be removed.

Comment: "If the top or bottom first value is positive then the range of cells from top or bottom whose sum is less than -50, then entire subset should be removed." -- so if top and bottom both > -50, remove all rows < -50?

Comment: If top and bottom both >-50 then see sum in the range from both top and bottom and if the sum from the range is <-50 then that subset should be removed else no action should be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cumany`. Combined with `filter`, it removes rows until a criterion is met (here `Profit <= -50`).

The first command is a way to parse your `Profit` column into a numeric column.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(Profit = parse_number(str_replace(Profit,"^-\\$(.*)$", "$-\\1"))) %>% 
  arrange(D30) %>% 
  filter(cumany(Profit > -50)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(D30)) %>% 
  filter(cumany(Profit > -50))


   Profit MRO_15x5    D30
1   275.0    0.141 -0.027
2  -162.5   -1.578 -0.051
3   337.5   -1.049 -0.055
4  -175.0   -0.183 -0.056
5   100.0   -1.043 -0.059
6  -175.0   -0.235 -0.061
7  -175.0   -4.062 -0.103
8   412.5   -1.524 -0.194
9  -175.0   -3.336 -0.205
10  150.0   -9.189 -0.240
11   12.5   -6.076 -0.248
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This will save much of my time to filter data. Highly appreciate this response.

Comment: Yes the results are absolutely according to requirements. Thank you for your support.